# Make a Gatling Post request with basicAuth in Gatling

Tags: json, scala, gatling

In my Gatling test I have this test:

```
  val HorizonPost: ChainBuilder = exec(
    http("Horizon Post")
      .post(getRouteInfoURI).basicAuth(s"${{EnvValues.RoadsApi_Username}}", s"${{EnvValues.RoadsApi_Password}}")
      .body(ElFileBody("bodies/horizonPost.json")).asJson
      .check(status.is(200))
  )
```

It seems that It has problems with the 'current_timestamp' and gives this error:

```
    body=
The request content was malformed:
Text '{{$current_timestamp}}' could not be parsed at index 0
```

The JSON file is:

```
 "locationTimestamp": "{{$current_timestamp}}",
```

Can someone explain what I need to change? I'm relatively new to Gatling.

Comment: Can you provide `horizonPost.json` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the JSON is:   "locationTimestamp": "{{$current_timestamp}}",

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use [Scala string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html), the correct syntax is `s"${foo}"`, not `s"${{foo}}"`.

If you're trying to use [Gatling Expression Language](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/), the correct syntax is `"${foo}"` (no `s`), not `s"${{foo}}"`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both but the Scala String interpolation is not accepted by IntelliJ, and with the Gatling Expression Language the test ends with: > Route Info call: Failed to build request: No attribute named '      2 (100,0%)
current_timestamp' is defined

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by storing the timestamp in a separate csv file, the only problem is that it is not the current_timestamp. 
Thanks for the possibilities.